# How to make absolutely positioned block draggable/scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login window that is absolutely positioned and center aligned.
On big screens PC/tablet and most mobile devices it looks fine.
But on some mobile devices small window height, when I click on some of the input fields and the keyboard layout appear, some part of the window is no longer visible and the user cannot see the input text being typed in.
The login window/modal can be scrolled/moved upward but up to a point where it reaches the top (`top: 0px`) and stops moving upwards, while the bottommost part is still not visible.
Here is an image:

[image]

I cannot scroll/move it more upwards, and part of it is still not visible.

Any idea how to make it movable so that when user drag it to move even more to the up - like `top: -100px`  for example?

This is part of the markup:

```
<style>
.authformCont {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      top: 4vh;
    }
.modal-dialog {
    all: unset;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    width: unset;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
    all: unset;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
</style>
<div class="authformCont" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-signin-module">
      <div class="modal-content">
       ..........
       ..........
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the parent relative to .authformCont?

Comment: The parent is relatively positioned

Comment: Show more code (html and css), please.

Comment: This attribute solved the problem for me : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior-block

On Safari though its a bit buggy - but still works